# How to measure how curvy the polyline is?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, graphing-functions, curves

I'm trying to make curve index which represents how curvy or how edgy the polyline is on the map. For example index might be 0 on straight line and high as line curves. I tried to use sum of absolutes of 2 times differential from Y(latitude)/X(longtitude) which is diff(diff(Y))/diff(X)^2 in R. But I'm not so sure it can really satisfy what I'm trying to achieve. Is there concept which is related to this?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHr8O.png)

Comment: Do you have examples you could show us? Is a polyline a sequence of connected line segments?

Comment: To be exact, it's bus route line on the map. So yes it is connected lines

Comment: Does the velocity of the buses matter? I ask this because you have some differential related tags and yet the paths are just straight line segments.

Comment: No, I'm trying to make spatial feature. And reason why I used differential tag is, I thought since differentiation help us to find tangent and change in tangent is directly related to curve, it might be answer

Comment: In general the idea is to compute "angle change" per "distance traveled". Both are cumulative properties, so you can compute a moving average, where you hold the distance relatively constant.